# Link to external js file not working <script src="client.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperlink, websocket, external

I've been playing with nodejs, using websockets to communicate between server and browser.
This is my working client code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io();
 socket.on('ida',function(data){
   console.log(data.news);
   socket.emit('vuelta',{news: 'answer'});
 });
</script>
```

Then why if I put

```
var socket = io();
 socket.on('ida',function(data){
   console.log(data.news);
   socket.emit('vuelta',{news: 'answer'});
 });
```

in a separated client.js file and link it like

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
<script src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it just doesn't work?
In the browser's console, instead of showing data.news it says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in client.js:1

Comment: The problem appears to be client.js, not the link to the script.

Comment: so what should be wrong with that? actually there is not even a < token in the 1st line of client.js

Comment: I can't help unless you upload the file.

Comment: $(document).ready (function client(){
 var socket = io();
 socket.on('ida',function(data){
  console.log(data.news);
  socket.emit('vuelta',{news: 'answer.'});
 });
});

Comment: that's my client.js linked in the html page with <script src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: could you post the html page?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  
 </body>
</html>

Comment: what about socket.io-1.3.7.js

Comment: it's weird because it actually works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you are not serving the file at all. Be careful to include it in the http server configuration, on your node server file.

Comment: Actually that was it! I was just serving my index.html and not the entire folder!